# React Native: White space around image

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am not able to remove white space around the "PRACTICIA" logo image and so my buttons are being pushed down to the bottom. Can someone please help me with this? My code is [here](https://github.com/samrao2/practiciatest)

My screenshot is down at the bottom. Here is the code for the entire app, its in the app.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  Button,
  FormLabel,
  FormInput,
  FormValidationMessage,
  Divider } from 'react-native-elements';

import { CardSection } from './src/components/CardSection';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'PRACTICIA'
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
<Image
style={{ flex: 1, height: 100, width: undefined }}
resizeMode="contain" source={require('./images/practicialogo.png')}
/>
<Text style={styles.textStyle}>Sign up as a...</Text>
<Divider style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="#3399ff"
        borderRadius={20}
          onPress={() => navigate('Teacher')}
          title="TEACHER"
        />
        <Divider style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />

        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="green"
        borderRadius={20}
          onPress={() => navigate('Parent')}
          title="PARENT"
        />
        <Divider style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />

        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="brown"
        borderRadius={20}
          onPress={() => navigate('Student')}
          title="ADULT STUDENT (18+)"
        />
        <Text style={styles.text2Style}>Already Registered?</Text>
        <Button
        raised
        flex='2'
        backgroundColor="grey"
        borderRadius={20}
          onPress={() => navigate('Login')}
          title="Login"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class TeacherSignUp extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'TEACHER SIGN UP',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
      <Divider style={{ height: 20, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Sign Up</Text>
        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <FormLabel>First Name</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <FormLabel>LastNme</FormLabel>
        <FormInput />
        <Divider style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
        <Button
        raised
        backgroundColor="brown"
        borderRadius={0}
          // onPress={() => navigate()}
          title="SUBMIT"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class ParentSignUp extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'PARENT SIGN UP',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Sign Up</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class StudentSignUp extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'ADULT STUDENT SIGN UP',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Sign Up</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'LOGIN',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
      <FormLabel>Email/Username</FormLabel>
      <FormInput />
      <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
      <FormInput />
      <Divider style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
      <Button
      raised
      backgroundColor="grey"
      borderRadius={0}
        // onPress={() => navigate()}
        title="SUBMIT"
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Teacher: { screen: TeacherSignUp },
  Parent: { screen: ParentSignUp },
  Student: { screen: StudentSignUp },
  Login: { screen: Login },

});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <SimpleApp />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#617189',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
},
text2Style: {
  alignSelf: 'center',
  color: '#617189',
  fontSize: 14,
  fontWeight: '300',
  paddingTop: 10,
  paddingBottom: 10
},
titleText: {
  fontSize: 20,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
},
});
```

here is the screenshot, there should not be that much white space around the logo:

[image: White space above and below image]

Here is the, image, which does not have that much white space, so i dont understand where the white space is coming from:

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing the 'flex: 1' from your Image?

Comment: Does the white space exist in the image file? I'd recommend adding a border to it, so you can know the real space the image is occupying in your screen, then you can adjust it. Also, it may be caused by that `flex: 1` in the `Image` component.

Comment: I Believe White Space is in your Logo Image .

Comment: @MarcosDemétrio i did try removing the flex 1 but then the image disappears altogether.

Comment: @SyedZainAli- i have attached the logo image about, there is not that much  which space in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

I believe the answer lies in the flex property. giving the image a prop of flex:1 will take up the entire container. So i played around with giving it a relative value and started with "1 / 2" (according to EsLint, those spaces in fraction are required). this at once solved the problem! I then played around with making the fraction larger and larger (3 / 4, 4 / 5, 7 / 8 etc.) till i got to where i wanted to be. This seemed to solve the issue. Result is below. Not sure its the only solution or even the best solution but it seems to work.  Happy to receive feedback and commentary.

Revised line of code: 
style={{ flex: 7 / 8, height: undefined, width: undefined }}

[image]

Comment: This isn't a great solution. Are you still living with this one?